# Realm database with encryption in android using Stetho, error to visualize into Chrome browser

Tags: android, encryption, realm, stetho

I would like to view my Realm database into Chrome browser by using Stetho on Windows.

When i not set the encryption key, i've no problem to visualize it, but since i've set it, my application crashes when i try to visualize the database throw my Chrome browser.

This is my source code in onCreate of my Application:

```
// Initialize Realm. Should only be done once when the application starts.
Realm.init(this);
RealmConfiguration realmConfiguration = new RealmConfiguration.Builder()
    .encryptionKey("myencryptionkey64bits into bytes[]")
    .deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded()
    .build();
Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(realmConfiguration);

// Create my RealmInspectorModulesProvider
RealmInspectorModulesProvider realmInspectorModulesProvider = RealmInspectorModulesProvider.builder(this)
    .withEncryptionKey("encrypted.realm", "myencryptionkey64bits into bytes[]")
    .build();

// Initialize Stetho
Stetho.initialize(Stetho.newInitializerBuilder(this)
    .enableDumpapp(Stetho.defaultDumperPluginsProvider(this))
    .enableWebKitInspector(realmInspectorModulesProvider)
    .build());
```

The exception:

```
E/REALM_JNI: jni: ThrowingException 5, Realm at path '/data/data/com.mypackage/files/default.realm' already opened with a different encryption key. in /Users/cm/Realm/realm-java/realm/realm-library/src/main/cpp/io_realm_internal_SharedRealm.cpp line 92, .
E/REALM_JNI: Exception has been throw: Unrecoverable error. Realm at path '/data/data/com.mypackage/files/default.realm' already opened with a different encryption key. in /Users/cm/Realm/realm-java/realm/realm-library/src/main/cpp/io_realm_internal_SharedRealm.cpp line 92
E/REALM_JNI: jni: ThrowingException 5, Realm at path '/data/data/com.mypackage/files/default.realm' already opened with different inMemory settings. in /Users/cm/Realm/realm-java/realm/realm-library/src/main/cpp/io_realm_internal_SharedRealm.cpp line 92, .
E/REALM_JNI: Exception has been throw: Unrecoverable error. Realm at path '/data/data/com.mypackage/files/default.realm' already opened with different inMemory settings. in /Users/cm/Realm/realm-java/realm/realm-library/src/main/cpp/io_realm_internal_SharedRealm.cpp line 92

E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: StethoWorker-main-19
Process: com.mypackage.debug, PID: 31197
io.realm.exceptions.RealmError: Unrecoverable error. Realm at path '/data/data/com.mypackage/files/default.realm' already opened with different inMemory settings. in /Users/cm/Realm/realm-java/realm/realm-library/src/main/cpp/io_realm_internal_SharedRealm.cpp line 92
    at io.realm.internal.SharedRealm.nativeGetSharedRealm(Native Method)
    at io.realm.internal.SharedRealm.getInstance(SharedRealm.java:205)
    at io.realm.internal.SharedRealm.getInstance(SharedRealm.java:182)
    at com.uphyca.stetho_realm.RealmPeerManager.openSharedRealm(RealmPeerManager.java:149)
    at com.uphyca.stetho_realm.RealmPeerManager.openSharedRealm(RealmPeerManager.java:128)
    at com.uphyca.stetho_realm.RealmPeerManager.getDatabaseTableNames(RealmPeerManager.java:55)
    at com.uphyca.stetho_realm.Database.getDatabaseTableNames(Database.java:124)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.facebook.stetho.inspector.MethodDispatcher$MethodDispatchHelper.invoke(MethodDispatcher.java:96)
    at com.facebook.stetho.inspector.MethodDispatcher.dispatch(MethodDispatcher.java:67)
    at com.facebook.stetho.inspector.ChromeDevtoolsServer.handleRemoteRequest(ChromeDevtoolsServer.java:129)
    at com.facebook.stetho.inspector.ChromeDevtoolsServer.handleRemoteMessage(ChromeDevtoolsServer.java:111)
    at com.facebook.stetho.inspector.ChromeDevtoolsServer.onMessage(ChromeDevtoolsServer.java:87)
    at com.facebook.stetho.websocket.WebSocketSession$1.handleTextFrame(WebSocketSession.java:176)
    at com.facebook.stetho.websocket.WebSocketSession$1.onCompleteFrame(WebSocketSession.java:136)
    at com.facebook.stetho.websocket.ReadHandler.readLoop(ReadHandler.java:44)
    at com.facebook.stetho.websocket.WebSocketSession.handle(WebSocketSession.java:45)
    at com.facebook.stetho.websocket.WebSocketHandler.doUpgrade(WebSocketHandler.java:117)
    at com.facebook.stetho.websocket.WebSocketHandler.handleRequest(WebSocketHandler.java:83)
    at com.facebook.stetho.server.http.LightHttpServer.dispatchToHandler(LightHttpServer.java:84)
    at com.facebook.stetho.server.http.LightHttpServer.serve(LightHttpServer.java:61)
    at com.facebook.stetho.inspector.DevtoolsSocketHandler.onAccepted(DevtoolsSocketHandler.java:52)
    at com.facebook.stetho.server.ProtocolDetectingSocketHandler.onSecured(ProtocolDetectingSocketHandler.java:63)
    at com.facebook.stetho.server.SecureSocketHandler.onAccepted(SecureSocketHandler.java:33)
    at com.facebook.stetho.server.LazySocketHandler.onAccepted(LazySocketHandler.java:36)
    at com.facebook.stetho.server.LocalSocketServer$WorkerThread.run(LocalSocketServer.java:167)
```

I confirm, i provide the same encryption key for Realm or Stetho. I think i missing wrong initialization of object Stetho?

Thanks for you help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The log says that you are trying to open `default.realm` not `encrypted.realm`.

Could you try `.withEncryptionKey("default.realm", "myencryptionkey64bits into bytes[]")` instead of `.withEncryptionKey("encrypted.realm", "myencryptionkey64bits into bytes[]")`?

Or you can use `.withDefaultEncryptionKey("myencryptionkey64bits into bytes[]")` instead if you are using the same key for all realm files.

Comment: My bad! Thanks so much to have see the problem with the filename! I use the default realm, so i use now `.withDefaultEncryptionKey("myencryptionkey64bits into bytes[]")` and all is fine!
Thanks you so much.